# JavaFX Input from Buttons

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-8

I'm creating a simple ATM machine GUI using javaFX but I can't seem to know how to take an input from a button. For instance, I created a virtual number pad but I don't know how to take input from clicked buttons.

```
public static void displayNumbers() {
    Stage window2 = new Stage();
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();

    window2.setTitle("Enter Value");

    Button one = new Button("1");
    Button two = new Button("2");
    Button three = new Button("3");
    Button four = new Button("4");
    Button five = new Button("5");
    Button six = new Button("6");
    Button seven = new Button("7");
    Button eight = new Button("8");
    Button nine = new Button("9");
    Button zero = new Button("0");
    Button enterButton = new Button("Enter");

    grid.add(one, 0, 0);
    grid.add(two, 1, 0);
    grid.add(three, 2, 0);
    grid.add(four, 0, 1);
    grid.add(five, 1, 1);
    grid.add(six, 2, 1);
    grid.add(seven, 0, 2);
    grid.add(eight, 1, 2);
    grid.add(nine, 2, 2);
    grid.add(zero, 1, 3);
    grid.add(enterButton, 2, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make a `Button` **do** something in JavaFX, you need to add an `EventHandler`. For example, let's tell button `one` to print something out to console:

```
one.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You just clicked Button #1!");
    }
});
```

This can be simplified with a lambda expression in JDK8+:

```
one.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("You just clicked Button #1!"));
```

---

If you need to execute more than one line of code when clicking the button, just use a code block instead:

```
one.setOnAction(event -> {
    // Do lots of things
});
```